# Custom Sudo Command

Tags: ubuntu, command, sudo, sudoers

So this is an idea I just had for efficiency is scripting. I'm wondering if it is possible to make a custom command (i.e. jello) that has sudo privileges, but doesn't prompt a password. I write a lot of scripts that require sudo permissions and don't like to type them in every time. I've been editing the sudoers file and making exceptions for these files. But I would really love if this were possible, so I could just type this command in my scripts and it would run like it should without asking for a password.

Comment: I am not an expert on Linuz and I don't know if it is possible - but have you considered that you might need a token (or worse, a plain-text password) in the script to make it possible? I hope your scripts are not meant for other people to use.

Comment: Hey, the script is only for my computer. I was just curious at the possibility. I don't want to have a huge security risk on the computer, that's why a special command would be nice because then only I would know it if I saw it. What is a token? I haven't heard that term before

Comment: you can set specific commands to have passwordless sudo access (to particular groups of users). In `/etc/sudoers` you can use a coammand like `usr ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/me/bin/custom_ping` to enable members of the group `usr` to run `custom_ping` that would usually require root password.

Comment: @Bonlenfum, if i read that correctly, that's what I am currently doing; giving particular scripts all sudo permissions without a password prompt. But, I'm guessing that there is no way to give a particular command passworldess sudo access that can be used to run scripts? I want to keep the sudo command "sacred" and have a separate command that is passwordless

Comment: I see, sorry my comment not helpful.  It seems that you can use wildcards on commands in the sudoers file, so perhaps you could keep all of your scripts that need sudo access have some common prefix/suffix, and make your sudoers rule match on that?  I've not tried wildcards myself -- seems more open to abuse than explicitly having a small set of special commands that get elevated. (see [docs](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html#x57696c646361726473) for the wildcard syntax)

Comment: @Bonlenfum, sweet! I'll give it a try

Comment: @user244985 a token is something that will allow you to authenticate a user without needing his password. Just like OpenId allows you to authenticate here with a Google account, for example - Stack Overflow never needs your Google account.

Comment: @Bonlenfum if your advice works, you should post it as an answer ;)

Comment: @Renan good point - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use wildcards in your sudoers file ([sudoers manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man5/sudoers.5.html)).

*Note: You'll need to take suitable precautions with any strategy like this because you necessarily won't know all of the commands that you are granting access ahead of time*
- [some exploits](http://blog.csnc.ch/2012/10/dangerous-sudoers-entries-part-4-wildcards/) and [risks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415291/1643946).

If the risks are acceptable to you, then putting something like this into your `/etc/sudoers` file will allow you to add new commands of the same form and enable running of those commands without typing your password every time:

```
me         ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/me/privil_scripts/priviledged_*.sh
```

Make sure it isn't easy for other users to drop in extra scripts in this directory! Comments on keeping this secure most welcome.

As a quick test:

```
# create a directory with some files inside
cd ~; mkdir nolook; touch nolook/f1; touch nolook/f2
>>> f1  f2
# make it so regular user can't see inside
sudo chmod -R 700 nolook; sudo chown -R root:root nolook
# test
ls nolook
>>> ls: cannot open directory nolook/: Permission denied
```

Now write privileged & unprivileged scripts:

```
echo "
#!/bin/sh
sudo ls nolook
" > privil_scripts/priviledged_ls.sh
chmod +x !$

echo "
#!/bin/sh
sudo ls nolook
" > privil_scripts/plain_ls.sh
chmod +x !$
```

and try them:

```
privil_scripts/priviledged_ls.sh
>>> f1  f2

privil_scripts/plain_ls.sh
>>> [sudo] password for me:
```

Comment: yes it did, sorry i haven't been on yet to mark it as the answer. Thank you